# Build query based on user input from Texbox and display it in another Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ado.net, db2

What I'm trying to achieve is to get one parameter from user (userID) which be stored in TextBox. User enter an example UserID in TextBox, click "View" button, some records from appropriate columns will be displayed in textBoxes placed on the screen. I don't want to use DataGrid because it always looks like table :).

The problem is that I dont know how to put user input into my DB2Command and then display some values from select in textboxes placed on the screen :/.

Here is my code:

View Button

```
        iDB2Connection nc = new iDB2Connection();
        nc.ConnectionString = "DataSource=vf05.it.volvo.se; DefaultCollection=VF05;";
        nc.Open();

        iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command("Select AAUSER, AANODE, AAORGN from     library.file where AAUSER = @UserID ", nc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", UserInput.Text);

        iDB2DataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

What code should I add to UserInput textBox and how I can display select result in textbox?
I could even user DataGrid and then display some values from DataGrid in textboxes but I don't know how to display ExecuteReader display in DataGrid. I probably should read some articles about data binding...

P.S

I was trying to put result of select statement into DataGrid using this

```
iDB2DataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dr;
```

where cmd was:

```
iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command("Select AAUSER, AANODE, AAORGN from T0T02PD.T0F001 where AAUSER = 'A0390944' ", nc);
```

This seems to work properly but anyway I want to put data from chosen columns into TextBoxes. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a TextBox with a Binding on a property in your ViewModel and put the binding in mode=TwoWay for update your ViewModel value from the user interface.

In your ViewModel:

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
```

In your Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserID, mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

After that you can store yours resulting items in a List and Bind it to a ItemsSource Property in a ListBox.

In your ViewModel:

```
public List<YourResultType> Items { get; private set; }
```

In your Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hello and thx for You answer. The problem is that I want to make that application pretty simple and I'm not sure if MVVM is the right choice here. Someone has suggested to use calibrum micro but this is to complicated for me unfortunately. I wish to have all knowledge which I need right now... I thought that I only need maybe few improvements in my code to test it further. What is wrong this this part of code ?? `iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command("Select AAUSER from T0T02PD.T0F001 where AAUSER = @UserID ", nc); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", UserInput.Text);`

Comment: I thought that the code above will get user input from UserInput TextBox and put it into query and then result of this query will be put into UserID TextBox. Here is the code to put query result into UserID TextBox : `iDB2DataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); UserID.DataContext = dr;`

Comment: You have to set the Text property not the DataContext..

And you should read the content of your DataReader to convert it to a string.

Comment: Yes I saw that two minutes ago but then I encountered bigger problem I think... I just can `UserID.Text = dr;` because I get this error `Cannot implicilty convert type IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2DataReader to string`. So the problem lies in `iDB2DataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`.

Comment: It isn't the DataReader who are false (or may be if he is empty). But you have to read is content before. Try something like this: 
`string content = string.Empty;
while (dr.Read())
{
content += dr["YourColumnName"];
}

UserID.DataContext = content`

Comment: Ye I've figured it that I have to read this first. Your code was almost perfect. I've had only to change this line `UserID.DataContext = content;` to this `UserID.Text= content;` and It works fine :)